# Countable infinite intersection of uncountable sets ist countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a series of uncountable sets. Is the the **countable infinite** intersection of them in every case countable? And if yes, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, suppose $A_i=\mathbb{R}$ for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i=\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. It's even worse, finite intersections of uncountable sets may still be uncountable, indeed, $A_1\cap A_2=\mathbb{R}$.